# Drupal - How can I let a Non-admin view (not edit) users

Tags: drupal

As an Admin, I can Find/View/Edit users in D6. I want a non-admin to be able to view user data (when they registered, their name and email) but NOT edit or change any info (esp. passwords).

Is there a module for this, or do I need to code a new permission.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

how about a view that fetches user name and email?